# HTML iframe with custom preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to create an iframe that allows you to view a custom-made preview. So currently I have this as my iframe code

```
<a class="hover">Example
 <iframe class="preview" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
</a>
```

and this script to enable hover preview

```
$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".preview").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".preview").hide();
});
```

However I want to be able to display my own, custom-made HTML in the iframe instead of a preview of a website. For example, if I hover over the name of a company, I want to be able to display information such as when it was founded, number of employees, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Dont need js

you can done by css

```
.preview{
  display:none;
}

.hover:hover .preview{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: But how can I input my own HTML into the frame?